# Wrapper for Boolean in NamedQuery

Tags: sql, oracle

I use Oracle SQL and have a table like this:

```
CREATE table MY_TABLE(
    MY_ID         RAW(16)                                NOT NULL CONSTRAINT MY_ID PRIMARY KEY,
    MY_BOOLEAN    NUMBER DEFAULT 1                       NOT NULL,
    MY_NAME       NUMBER                                 NOT NULL
);
```

`MY_BOOLEAN` can be `0` (means false) or `1` (means true).

My application can search for  values with a `NamedQuery`. This looks like this:

```
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
...
@NamedQuery(
    name = "MyTable.listAllMatching",
    query = "SELECT COUNT(t) FROM MyTable t WHERE "
            + "LOWER(t.id) LIKE LOWER(:filter) OR "
            + "LOWER(t.myBoolean) LIKE LOWER(:filter) OR "
            + "LOWER(t.myName) LIKE LOWER(:filter)"
)
```

It works, if I search for the name for example. If I search for `true`, I want to get all rows in which `MY_BOOLEAN` is `1`. Same for `false` and `0`. I can't just search for `0` or `1` because when I search for `0` for example, I also get every row which has a `0` in their `MY_ID`.

Is there a way to use a wrapper function or whatever to convert the `true` or `false` in `:filter` to `0` or `1` just for `MY_BOOLEAN`? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: OT: your query will be very slow. 1st you apply a function onto a column ( so you should use functional index) 2nd you you three different search criteria - so no index can be used. You should split your query into three different ones if your filters are distinct. PS: also boolean is usually implemented as `CHAR(1)` in Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be done a little differently. By declaring a MY_BOOLEAN and MY_NAME as a number and then using LOWER in your query you are causing an explicit conversion of number to VARCHAR.  Try this instead

```
    query = "SELECT COUNT(t) FROM MyTable t WHERE "
        + "(LOWER(t.id) LIKE LOWER(:filter1) "
        + " OR LOWER(t.my_Name) LIKE LOWER(:filter1))"
        + " t.my_Boolean = :filter2"
```

By putting brackets around the OR you get your choice and by using MyBoolean as a numeric comparison it acts as an overall filter

After re reading what you are trying to do I think you need two filters, one for text, declared as CHAR, and one for the MyBoolean and my_name.

As an aside you could have more clarity by naming your columns differently

```
my_name => my_name_id
my_boolean => enabled
```